# Schengen visa: duration of stay is longer than validity?

Tags: schengen-visas

Just got my schengen visa from Germany. Validity is 17days,but duration is 20days. Can I stay 18days from the start date till the date right after then end date in the validity? This is really confusing. I have not seen anyone with longer duration than validity, normally it is the other way. Thanks?!!

---

[image]

I applied visa for 7-24 Aug but ticket not avail for 24th so I booked till 25th Aug 11am. Will it be OK? Will they even let me enter Germany from the first place? I saw some post say I can go to the airport 24th midnight then try to extend there or just stay there wait till my flight at 11am on 25th?it this feasible? Appreciate any reply!

Comment: What did you request? How do the dates you've been given relate to your planned travel dates?

Comment: It might be helpful to post a picture of the visa or vignette, having blocked out the personal data.

Comment: You may not be present for a larger number of days than authorized in the duration of stay field.  Any part of a calendar day counts as one day.  You may not stay past the expiration date.  The longer duration than validity is a weird mistake. It does not allow you to exceed the validity period.

Comment: Hi guys added photo and further detail. Thanks

Comment: Contact the consulate immediately.

Comment: Contact for? To extend the validity? As I applied visa with ticket reserved for 7-24 Aug.

Comment: You applied for 7-24 Aug but booked your ticket for 25th? In the hope of being able to go through Immigration before midnight on 24th? I doubt that’s feasible

Comment: I doubt too. You need to contact the consulate indeed, ask for an extension and explanation of the 20 days vs the validity. Validity has priority however, so you must leave on the 24th as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

Going through passport control leaving the Schengen Area several hours early to get stamped out on the right side of midnight might not be possible. Your boarding pass might no be accepted at that time.

You do plan to overstay, which at least theoretically could prevent you from being admitted to the Schengen Area, which would be far worse than getting caught leaving a little bit too late.

Sometimes a Schengen visa is issued with a little bit longer validity than the original itinerary, to allow for reasonable changes like in your case. The maximum stay of 20 days for a proposed 17-day trip might indicate that they were going to give you some wiggle room. As a Schengen visa must remain valid for the duration of the visit you cannot possible make use of your 20 days during that 17-day period. The embassy seems to have made a mistake.

I would contact the embassy and politely ask for a new visa with an extra day.