# Why is it required to submit proof of residence and proof of airplane ticket for Schengen Visa?

Tags: schengen, germany, schengen-visas, india

Some countries which have Schengen Visa have certain curious properties when being applied from certain **"third world countries"**. This curious points I see relates to the requirements for applying the Visa. For applying for the visa, there are four main things required, to my understanding, on top of the traditional documents:

1. Proof of Accomodation
2. Proof of Plane Reservation
3. Proof of Health Insurance
4. Proof of Financing

I am entirely confused on what the point of 1. and 2. is actually. After one submits all the above information, and they get the Schengen Visa, the Visa is given for fixed time like 90 days. In this ninty days apparently one can have any travel to Schengen countries with trouble given that they stay mainly in the particular country from whose Embassy they took the Schengen Visa. Furthermore one has to give only a reservation. So, the issue is not even financial because anyone can cancelled a reservation whether they get a reservation or not.

**If once one has the Visa all this information of the actual technical dates or reservations is forgotten inside the Visa, what was the point of giving it?** Clearly this opens up a lot of chance and areas for abuse which is being used by some Tourist agencies by creating a provisional hotel booking/ aero plane ticket which is cancelled immediately after the ticket.

I have read in some site that this illegal/ legal grey area and some site where people say they have done for life long without any issues. I also have visited some Travel Consultation places where their whole premise is that they will find a provisional stay for the sake of making the Visa and would later be cancelled.

**If the above was truly an abuse/ illegal, I am pretty sure the Schengen countries could have found out about it by now.**

So, again, What on earth is the point of giving the technical dates and proof of bookings? Is this all just a formality?

Comment: This is completely incorrect, you state a flight and accomodation, and the visa might be given exactly for those dates, there is no guarantee that you will get a 90 day visa.

Comment: Really? I thought it was always 90 days. Let me check

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://schengen.europ-assistance.com/en/how-long-schengen-visa-valid%23:~:text%3DThe%2520duration%2520of%2520stay%2520within,6%2520months%2520to%25205%2520years.&ved=2ahUKEwiAwZmx7J74AhU48rsIHa1QB1kQFnoECBIQBQ&usg=AOvVaw34bh9t682lB-k1wOlynz_S

Comment: That's not an official site. 90 days means the maximum stay you can have, not the duration of the visa you will get, you can get less if your stay is not justified for 90 days, say if you go to a conference that lasts a week.

Comment: So could you please point to an official site to validate your claim. It seems I can't find this by my ability to Google. @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: Sure, https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/schengen-borders-and-visa/schengen-visa_en, it clearly states: "an intended stay in the territory of the Schengen States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180 days period ("short stay visa"),"

Comment: But that is giving the maximum. The query is the visa always hitting the maximum or be strictly below it @Dr.Snoopy

Answer (score 2):

It is requested because the visa issuing country has no obligation to give you the full 90 days. They can issue any duration they see fit.

Here is an example of a short stay visa with duration of stay and validity shorter than the maximum 90 days:
[Schengen visa: duration of stay is longer than validity?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141571/schengen-visa-duration-of-stay-is-longer-than-validity)

Comment: Well damn, I am suprised. Everyone I talked to where I live and have gone there seems to have obtained it for the total ninty days , so I was a bit suprised to see this